# How to disable some js scripts on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, dom, mobile

i read some topics but they are was not helpfully

i have 4 script like

```
<script src="http://kleaz.com/fsc/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kleaz.com/fsc/Projector.js"></script>
<script src="http://kleaz.com/fsc/CanvasRenderer.js"></script>
<script src="http://kleaz.com/fsc/me.js"></script>
```

I don't want to load these scripts on mobile devices so if my window width smaller then 780px i don't want my device will load these scripts.

how it can be possible?

Comment: You can load `scripts` asynchronously...Search about it.. Loading them with conditions will help!

Comment: Aka, turn your logic around. Only load those script when the windows bigger than 780. You can dynamically add scripts by making a new script tag and inserting it into the body after setting its src.

Comment: Surely this is a duplicate. Simply detect screen width, and if 780 or less, don't load the scripts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only load the scripts if the screen size is greater than 780px, something long the lines of:

```
if (window.screen.width > 780) {
  document.write( 
    '<script src="http://kleaz.com/fsc/three.min.js"><\/script>' +
    '<script src="http://kleaz.com/fsc/Projector.js"><\/script>' +
    '<script src="http://kleaz.com/fsc/CanvasRenderer.js"><\/script>' +
    '<script src="http://kleaz.com/fsc/me.js"><\/script>'
  )
}
```

Though you may want to use DOM methods to add the script elements rather than *doucment.write*.

Answer (score 1):

Try your scripts in following code:

```
function isMobile() {
return /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
}

if (!isMobile()) {
//place script you don't want to run on mobile here
//TRY YOUR SCRIPT AS FOLLOWING WAY!!!
document.write('<script src="http://kleaz.com/fsc/three.min.js"></script>');
document.write('<script src="http://kleaz.com/fsc/Projector.js"></script>');
document.write('<script src="http://kleaz.com/fsc/CanvasRenderer.js"></script>');
document.write('<script src="http://kleaz.com/fsc/me.js"></script>');
}
```

Comment: I tired this `<script type="text/javascript">
 function isMobile() {
return /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
}

if (!isMobile()) {
<script src="http://kleaz.com/fsc/three.min.js"></script>

  <script src="http://kleaz.com/fsc/Projector.js"></script>
  <script src="http://kleaz.com/fsc/CanvasRenderer.js"></script>
  <script src="http://kleaz.com/fsc/me.js"></script>


}
</script>   but that time page not load my scripts on desktop too `

Comment: Are you sure that *every* iPad has a screen size less than 780px? And every IEMobile device? And that every device that includes any one of those words in the Navigator string is actually one of those devices?